# How to use batch account created with user subscription in Data Factory Linked Service?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I have created a Batch Service with **user subscription** and **created a key vault** also,

http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/article/de/Images/image007.jpg

Now how can I use that batch service in the Data Factory Linked Service.
Because it is asking for access key.

What Key I have to give here?

I have created a Key from Key Vault, it created as a Version, starting time and Expiration time but unable to fine the key.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for these:

I found 2 Sources for you:

**Source 1:**

- Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-account-create-portal
- pay special attention under section >> **Additional configuration for user subscription mode**

  It further goes and talks about `creating a key vault`.

Quote

```
Create a key vault

In user subscription mode, an Azure key vault is required that belongs to the same resource group as the Batch account to be created. Make sure the resource group is in a region where Batch is available and which your subscription supports.

* In the Azure portal, click New > Security + Identity > Key Vault.
* In the Create Key Vault page, enter a name for the key vault, and create a resource group in the region you want for your Batch account. Leave the remaining settings at default values, then click Create.
```

**Source 2:**

I have ported all the images from the [source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-the-batch-services-user-subscription-mode-in-the-azure-portal/).

I will add most of the screenshot from this link: so that this Post does not become the link only post.

- At this stage I have not tried by myself but my source is [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-the-batch-services-user-subscription-mode-in-the-azure-portal/). Let me know if it helps.

**Follow these steps to create a key vault for your Batch Services**

In User Subscription mode, an Azure key vault is required which belongs to the same resource group where the Batch account is to be created. Also, we are going to create the Batch Services with User Subscription.

Click New >> Compute and select Batch Service.

[image]

**Then**

In the "New Batch Creation" blade, choose the descriptions as in the image below. For creating the storage account I have chosen the exsisting account, however, if you don't have one then choose the "Create New" option to create a new storage account. Then, choose POOL ALLOCATION to the User Subscription.

[image]

**Then**

For creating the new key vault, choose "Create a new vault" then give the desired description for your vault, and choose "Create" to create the Key Vault.

[image]

**Then**

For keyvault, it shows the newly created key vault. Next, we choose to pin our Batch Service into the dashboard and click "Create" to create the account.

[image]

**Then**

After deployment, we are able to see our Batch Service with User Subscription in detail.

[image]

Comment: Has anyone successfully reproduced this? I created the key vault, connected batch account, data factory that sees the key vault and batch account. Data factory is listed as the principal for using secrets for that key vault, but the factory is not able to link the batch pool. Error: `Can not access user batch account, please check batch account settings.` Is there a need to link the specific secret in the batch account?

Answer (score 0):

It's required to provide Batch Account Access Key in Data Factory Linked Service. It has nothing to do with Keys/Secrets stored in Azure Key Vault.

To get Access Key go to Azure Portal, open your Batch Account, navigate to Keys tab and select any of keys listed there. Keys tab should look like this:

[image: Key Tab Screenshot]

Comment: I didn't see these types of keys, I had created the batch account in User Subscription Mode.

Comment: This is not possible with Batch accounts created under User Subscription. For that you really need the Key vault approach